# Duplicate Titles needing improvement and/or closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, question-title

Inspired by a [similar question on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104586/156902), I just did [this database query](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/s/1802/find-identical-titles-no-closed-questions) on serverfault, and found 262 pairs of questions with totally identical title, excluding those where one of them is already closed.  (There are some merged questions in the list, if those were not closed before merging.)

- In some cases these might be simple duplicates, then vote to close. (If you think the to-be-closed one has valuable answers, you might flag it for moderator attention, so it can be merged.)
- In other cases one or both questions might have a bad title, then edit the title (and maybe the text and tags, if you are on it) to make them better (and distinct).

Happy editing/voting!

Comment: Looks like it doesn't exclude merged questions (ie [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/137292/how-can-i-pre-sign-puppet-certificates)/[this](http://serverfault.com/questions/19462/how-can-i-pre-sign-puppet-certificates)).  Great query though, thanks!

Comment: By the way, on my [similar superuser question](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3347/67711) nhinkle added some guidelines for flagging. Being a total foreigner to Serverfault, I'll let this for the SF crowd to guess how to handle it here.

Comment: @Shane: I found no way to exclude merged questions, only closed ones. I thought closing would be a prerequisite for merging, but it seems not to be so.

Comment: Looks like a goldmine for getting the Marshall badge ;)

Comment: @Dana: Please don't flood the moderator's flag queue, the moderators might not like too many such flags. This is firstly meant for users who can already vote to close.

Comment: May be better to start a queue of specific questions to vote on then. A duplicate question is a duplicate question though.

Comment: @Dana: There is this [Vote to close chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/161/server-fault-vote-to-close). But wait on your moderators to say whether you should or should not flag.

Comment: I would suggest that using the vote to close option is the most constructive, but if you feel they need a mod to close, or that they need merging please do flag them.

Answer (score 1):

Status: In Progress